# How to create html from markdown with derived class values

Tags: html, css, markdown

I have a markdown file:

```
# P1
## C1
### S1
Foo

Foo

Foo

---

Foo 

Foo

Foo
```

Using Pandoc I can convert to a basic html file:

```
<h1>P1</h1>
<h2>C1</h2>
<h3>S1</h3>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
<hr />
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
```

However what I would like is a programmatic way to give the first `<p>` following each `<h3>` or `<hr/>` one class, and all other `<p>`s another, giving:

```
<h1>P1</h1>
<h2>C1</h2>
<h3>S1</h3>
<p class="a">Foo</p>
<p class="b">Foo</p>
<p class="b">Foo</p>
<hr />
<p class="a">Foo</p>
<p class="b">Foo</p>
<p class="b">Foo</p>
```

I'd like to know what sort of solution I'm looking at, i.e. is there a tool that can help here, or am I looking at some coding. Prefer the former.

Comment: Will those paragraphs always _directly_ follow the h3 / hr, or can there be other elements in between? If the former, and you only need this for formatting purposes - then you don't need these classes, the selector `h3 + p, hr + p` will do.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of selectors, but I'm looking for a different outcome here.

Comment: You could use those same selectors in JavaScript, to select those elements - and then add your class to it.

Comment: I think I get that logically, but no idea how to implement. Is there a resource that might help learn how to do this? I don't know javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this for paragraphs immediately following a h3 or hr, the CSS selector `h3 + p, hr + p` would do.

You can use that same selector to select the elements in JavaScript, to loop over them, and then add the class.

I am adding the `b` class to *all* paragraphs first here, and then for the "special" ones I remove the `b` class again, and add `a`. (Simpler, than somehow "reversing" the selection, to only add `b` to the non-special elements only.)

```js
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p'),
  specialParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll('h3 + p, hr + p');

paragraphs.forEach(p => p.classList.add('b'))
specialParagraphs.forEach(p => {
  p.classList.remove('b');
  p.classList.add('a')
})
```

```css
.a {
  color: red;
}

.b {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>P1</h1>
<h2>C1</h2>
<h3>S1</h3>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
<hr />
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Foo</p>
```

Comment: OK I see how that works now. By embedding the javascript into the html, a browser can run the JS to modify the html rendered. But my html file is still essentially left unmodified. Is there a way to do this without relying on a browser? I'm looking for a fully CLI solution ideally.

Comment: You could run something similar via node.js, for example.

Comment: Any chance of a small example?

Comment: No, sorry, not my area of expertise.